# Return top 5 from SUM in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to return the following statement but I only want to return the TOP 5 of each Sale value only.....not all the records.

```
Select ID, Code, sum(Sale) as Sale from TableName
Where Code = 11
Group By ID, code
```

**I do not want this!**

```
Select TOP 5 ID, Code, sum(Sale) as Sale from TableName
Where Code = 11
Group By ID, code
```

Comment: The top 5 total sales, or the sum of the top 5 sales for each group?

Comment: I want to return only the top 5 results for each group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
With Cte as 
( Select  ID, Code, sale as Sales ,
  row_number() over (partition by ID,code order by sale desc) as row_num 
  from TableName where code=11
)
Select Id,code,sum(sales) from cte 
GROUP BY ID, code
WHERE row_num < 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH TopSales AS (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Code ORDER BY Sale DESC) saleRank
  FROM TableName
)
SELECT ID, Code, SUM(Sale) AS Sale
  FROM TopSales
  WHERE (Code = 11) AND (saleRank <= 5)
  GROUP BY ID, code
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like:

```
;WITH sales (
SELECT
 id, 
 code,
 sale,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, code ORDER BY sales DESC) n
FROM
 TableName
WHERE
 Code = 11
)
SELECT
 id, code, sum(sale) sale
FROM
 sales
WHERE
 n <= 5
GROUP BY
 id,
 code
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY` help to find last 5 sales. Then you `SUM` only top (highest) 5.

This query returns sum of top 5 sales for each (id, code) group.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, code, SUM (sale) 
from
(
    select id, code, sale, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id, code order by sale desc) rn 
    from tablename
) v
where rn<=5
group by id, code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return just the top 5 results for each group you could do this:

```
with cte as 
(ID, Code, Sale,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by  ID,
Code order by (select 0)) rownum
from TableName)
Select ID, Code, sum(Sale) as Sale from cte
Where Code = 11
and rownum<=5
Group By ID, code
```

If you want to return  top 5 results with highest salary for each group you could do this:

```
with cte as 
(ID, Code, Sale,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by  ID,
Code order by Sale desc) rownum
from TableName)
Select ID, Code, sum(Sale) as Sale from cte
Where Code = 11
and rownum<=5
Group By ID, code
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id, code, sum(sale) as sale from tablename
where code = 11
group by id, code
order by sum(sale) desc
limit 5
```

Comment: This is tagged as SQL-Server, the `ORDER BY` / `LIMIT` technique is for MySQL only.